# Creating a variable seen by all opened pages in one window, is it possible?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way in JavaScript to have a variable that would stay "alive" and accessible across all pages opened within one window?

I have created two pages dog.php and cat.php.

dog.php goes like this:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
MyWord = "Bingo";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = window.MyWord;
</script>

<p><a href="http://example.com/my_wnd_obj/cat.php">go to the cat page</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

and the cat.php is this:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="KittyTalks"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("KittyTalks").innerHTML = window.MyWord;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However the cat.php reads "undefined" instead of "Bingo", which means that the cat.php page doesn't see the variable MyWord created in dog.php.

Is there any way to make it see that variable?

Comment: HTML5 [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: @Abdul - Can you, please, elaborate? Is LocalStorage a kind of function?

Comment: It's essentially a key-value pair storage in the browser. You just need to be careful about resetting or overwriting the keys at proper times

Comment: @brilliant an actual link was included with that comment - did you follow it?

Comment: @Abdul - Ah! I see. Thank you.

Comment: @brilliant To expand on the carefulness on resetting/overwriting keys, you might overwrite a key on one page, that was set and is used on another page, and another page expects the older key to be the same. So care is needed, since it's like a shared variable with multiple threads accessing it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not quite a variable, but you could use [Session Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). To implement your example, you might do:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('MyWord', 'Bingo');
```

on the first page, and then

```
document.getElementById("KittyTalks").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem('MyWord');
```

on the second page.

If you want to get a little fancier, you could [define a property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). On both pages you would put code like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, "MyWord",
    {
        get:()=>sessionStorage.getItem("MyWord"),
        set:(val)=>sessionStorage.setItem("MyWord", val)
    }
);
```

Then you could use it like a regular variable.

Comment: WOW! This is just amazing! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use localstorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Something like this on dog.php:

```
localStorage.setItem('MyWord', 'Bingo');
```

and then on cat.php:

```
var myWord = localStorage.getItem('MyWord');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use local storage!

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

But remember that this variable will be visible for all windows/future sessions on the same host!

```
// Store
localStorage.lastname = "Smith";
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.lastname;
```

Comment: I can't see the downside of that solution... Hope someone can explaing it.